# How to confirm whether a web page has been cached or not in browser?

Tags: http, caching, https, http-headers, browser-cache

I have a JSP which ensures that the HTTP response contains headers to instruct browsers not to cache. I accessed that 
page in Firefox with Firebug open and could see in Firebug under 'Net' - 'HTML' - 'Headers' 'Response Headers'

```
    Cache-Control   no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    Content-Type    text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
    Date            Sun, 26 Oct 2014 22:47:28 GMT
    Expires         Sat, 6 May 1995 12:00:00 GMT
    Pragma          no-cache
    Transfer-Encoding chunked
```

Is this information enough to say the page is not cached or is there any other way to double check whether a 
page has been cached or not in browser?

Comment: Yes, but the easy way to confirm it is navigate (via links) from this page to another page and then back to this one. If you get an HTTP 200 response the page is not cached.

Comment: I would go to the Net tab and look at Status column. If it's 200 OK it means the resource (image, js, etc) has been loaded ex-novo, 304 Not Modified means it's been cached.

Comment: @scunliffe,@Paolo - Possibly I'm missing something, I navigated back to the page which got headers mentioned above and checked status as well, first case I could access the page and status also comes as 200.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of this post -[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884513/avoid-caching-of-the-http-responses]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found CacheViewer2 add-on in Firefox, that lists resources that got cached in Firefox. Now I'm able to confirm whether the page has been cached or not. This add-on has been mentioned [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Browser_cache_weakness_(OTG-AUTHN-006))